# Disable a module (specifically Lightbox) in Drupal with Mobile theme

Tags: drupal, mobile, module, lightbox

We are building a mobile version of an existing Drupal site. Lightbox is used to display images. This uses Javascript, which is unwise on mobile websites.

We are using Drupal with Mobile Tools. Is there a way to disable the lightbox module on the mobile version? 
Or can we exclude that module in our mobile theme?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Lightbox2 module, if not consider using it since it has page exclusion capability: exclude certain pages on your site from having the lightbox2 functionality. In administration there is a group **Page specific lightbox2 settings** where
you can specify pages/paths (of mobile site) where Lightbox2 will load or not.

Comment: That's right, Lightbox2. The problem is that the mobile site doesn't use specific pages; it just uses a different theme, optimized for mobile. So we cannot include or exclude pages that should('nt) use the lightbox. A parameter ?gomobile=true is passed for mobile versions.

Comment: I think I can use that parameter: whenever gomobile=true, I can activate JavaScript that will remove the "rel=lightbox" tag from image links. Any thoughts?

Comment: you could override/remove js/css in template.php, here is an example: http://www.mediacurrent.com/blogs/remove-or-replace-jscss-page